# Varargs with different type in method overloading in Java

Tags: java

I have two function as follow:

```
public static Method findMethodBestMatch(String methodName, Class<?>... parameterTypes) {
}

public static Method findMethodBestMatch(String methodName, Object... args) {
}
```

Then when I call `findMethodBestMatch("xx")`, the compiler confused both function match. My question is how can I specify one method to call.

Comment: I think you could pass an empty array as a second argument, eg. `findMethodBestMatch("xx", new Object[0])`

Comment: Can you specify the exact error that the compiler outputs? In my IDE, it matches the first method.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Which version of Java, and which compiler are you using?

Comment: I think there isn't any error - OP just wants to be able to differentiate between the two when calling it with just one argument.

Comment: OP, Is @Amongalen right?

Comment: I don't think this would be ambiguous: the `Class<?>...` overload is more specific, so that one would be selected.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, if you have two methods that could be called but parameters of one are more specific than the other, then it runs the one more specific. In your example, `Class` is a subclass of `Object` and because of that it will always pick the first method.

However, if instead of `Class...` and `Object...` you would have `Integer...` and `String...` it won't compile. One of the two needs to extend the other one.

What it means that one method is more specific than other:

> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time error. In cases such as an explicitly typed lambda expression argument (§15.27.1) or a variable arity invocation (§15.12.2.4), some flexibility is allowed to adapt one signature to the other.

You can read more in [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)

For your question on how to call a specific one: `Object...` is simply an array of `Object`. Because of that you could always just pass an empty array, like so:

```
findMethodBestMatch("xx", new Class<?>[0]); // calls the first implementation
findMethodBestMatch("xx", new Object[0]); // calls the second implementation
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Class `Class` inherits from Class `Object` (as any class does) when you try to pass array of `Class` it could fit both methods. Leave just one method with `Object...` param and in the method differentiate between the different types.

Comment: What happens when a `Class` element is to be rightfully used as an `Object[]` element (alongside something like `"abc"`)? I'm sure there's a reason the OP wants to overload and treat the parameters differently.